# system.outofmemoryexception with binaryblob and large file using through NHibernate

Tags: nhibernate

system.outofmemoryexception with binaryblob and large file using through NHibernate. I can upload upto 45 MB file, if it exceeds that i am getting system out of memory exception.

Answer (score 0):

NHibernate wasn't designed for handling such a big blobs. Use build-in database streaming capabilities. If you are using MS SQL then you could use SqlFileStream class.